# Yammer login display a 400 error page

Tags: yammer

I have both an embedded yammer login button and I tried through code to login and both return a 400 error page in the popup for the login. What can cause this?

```
 yam.login(function (response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            postActivity();
                         }
```

Comment: The page it is navigating to is: https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&client_id=

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    <span id="yammer-login"></span>
    <script> 
        $(function(){

            yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) { 
                if (resp.authResponse) { 
                    //your code that 
                    document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Yammer!'; 
                } 
            });
         });
```